# Table data from View not getting posted to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller, ajaxform

Here is a portion of my view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveScheduleType", "Users", new {   }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "", LoadingElementId = "imgloaderIndex" }, new { id = "addUserForm" }))
{  
    <table id="tblScheduleType" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="edit popuptable" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        @{ 
            if (Model.DataList != null && Model.DataList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var sch in Model.DataList)
                {
            <tr>
                <td class="lblForTdName" width="250px">@sch.Name
                </td>
                <td class="ctrlForTdName" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="text" value="@sch.Name" />
                </td>
                <td class="lblForTdDesc" width="250px">@sch.Description
                </td>
                <td class="ctrlForTdDesc" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="text" value="@sch.Description" />
                </td>
                <td class="lblForTd">
                    <a class="editScheduleType">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td class="ctrlForTd" style="display:none;">
                    <a class="updateScheduleType">Update</a>
                    <a class="cancelScheduleType">Cancel</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="deleteScheduleType">Delete</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
                }
            }
        }
    </table>
<br clear="all" />
 <input type="submit" id="" value="SAVE" />
 <br clear="all" />
}
```

As you can see i have data in the form of a table in the view. On click of a submit button I want the data in the table to pass from the view to controller, but I'm not getting the data inside the controller. I checked by putting a break point.

Here is the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveScheduleType(Response<ScheduleType> scheduleType)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your text fields have a name attribute.  You have to have the name match the property in Response for this to work, including using dot notation for models with complicated objects.

To make it even harder, you need to render a name with array syntax, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="DataList[0].Name" />
```

In order to get it to post back correctly.